# Unable to detect bad data for bulk import from CSV using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, import, oledb

For instance, if a date column includes an added letter, it gets treated as a null and I don't get any warning.

I exhausted all of Microsoft's documentation and there is no indication this behavior can be changed. Only found one article in all of google that delt with this and it said can't be changed.

The schema.ini is created through code, but this is what it looks like.

```
[NewEmployees.csv]
ColNameHeader=True
Format=CSVDelimited
DateTimeFormat=dd-MMM-yy
Col1=FirstName Text
Col2=LastName Text
Col3="Hire Date" Date
```

Below is the most relevant lines of code

```
string strSql = "SELECT * FROM [" + FileUpload1.FileName + "]";
                string strCSVConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + targetFolder + ";" + "Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;'";
                OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, strCSVConnString);
                DataTable importData = new DataTable();
                oleda.Fill(importData);

                GridView1.DataSource = importData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
```

If anyone wants the entire ASP.Net code than it is shown below. It will allow a user to select a file on their computer, create a folder whose name is based on the current date and time, create a schema.ini and save it to the folder, save the uploaded csv file to the folder, than query the csv file and bind it to a gridview. It's good code but useless if it can't detect bad data.

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class EmployeeImport : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string GetDateTimeStampedFolderName()
        {
            return string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}", DateTime.Now);
        }

        public void CreateSchemIni(string targetFolder, string fileName)
        {
            using (FileStream filestr = new FileStream(targetFolder + "/schema.ini", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filestr))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("[" + FileUpload1.FileName + "]");
                    writer.WriteLine("ColNameHeader=True");
                    writer.WriteLine("Format=CSVDelimited");
                    writer.WriteLine("DateTimeFormat=dd-MMM-yy");
                    writer.WriteLine("Col1=FirstName Text");
                    writer.WriteLine("Col2=LastName Text");
                    writer.WriteLine("Col3=\"Hire Date\" Date");
                    writer.Close();
                    writer.Dispose();
                }
                filestr.Close();
                filestr.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void UploadAndImport()
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string targetFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Employees/" + GetDateTimeStampedFolderName());

                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetFolder) == false)
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetFolder);
                }

                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(targetFolder, FileUpload1.FileName));

                CreateSchemIni(targetFolder, FileUpload1.FileName);

                string strSql = "SELECT * FROM [" + FileUpload1.FileName + "]";
                string strCSVConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + targetFolder + ";" + "Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;'";
                OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, strCSVConnString);
                DataTable importData = new DataTable();
                oleda.Fill(importData);

                GridView1.DataSource = importData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                UploadAndImport();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EmployeeImport.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.EmployeeImport" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

         <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload" 
            onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like flooding...

Comment: What is flooding? Perhaps I put too much detail and you put too little?

Comment: @JCM - sorry for the smart alec remark. I re-edited my post and hopefully made it better.

Comment: CSV is a text file so perhaps try a text file method to bind your data. The ACE driver is suprisingly bug ridden and inflexible particularly around data types and has been forever (since DTS days).

Comment: You should give http://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadFileDelimited/ a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 significant silent but deadly problems that can arise from using the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 along with schema.ini to import data. I am posting a solution to both. Although one of them only works with SQL Server, a similar solution may work for other databases.

1. Bad data such as a date with a letter such as "5/20/2016a" will be
   converted to null and it does not throw an exception or warning when
   that happens. It will merrily go about its way and corrupt your data.
2. Specifying column type in the schema.ini is done by it's ordinal
   position and will completely ignore the headers in the CSV. If columns are out of sequence in the CSV you will **not** get an exception or warning. And your data will be corrupted.

For example, if the schema.ini contains:

```
Col1=FirstName Text
Col2=LastName Text
Col3="Hire Date" Date
```

And the CSV has FirstName,LastName in the wrong order:

```
LastName,FirstName,HireDate
Smith,Jon,5/1/2016
Moore,Larry,5/15/2016
```

The ACE driver is not smart enough to recognize that the headers are out of order and the data will be imported incorrectly.

**Solution to problem 1 - Bad Data**

The solution I came up with is to use the schema.ini to specify all columns as text fields and use the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy to import the data to SQL Server. When SQLBulkCopy finds bad data, it is smart enough to throw an exception and block the import of the entire CSV, even if only the last record is bad.

**Solution to problem 2 - CSV columns are out of order, or contain missing/extra columns**

To solve this problem I created 2 DataTables, one is filled with schema and no data. The one that is filled with only schema must be done prior to creating the schema.ini, as once the schema.ini is created, the headers in the CSV will be ignored.

```
DataTable importData = new DataTable();
DataTable importDataSourceSchema = new DataTable();

// Fill the schema prior to creating the schema.ini, as this is the only way to get the headers from the CSV
oleda.FillSchema(importDataSourceSchema, System.Data.SchemaType.Source);
CreateSchemIni(targetFolder, FileUpload1.FileName);
oleda.Fill(importData);
```

I then created a function that validates the headers in the CSV are in the correct order and that the CSV contains the correct number of columns:

```
private bool ValidateHeaders(DataTable importData, DataTable importDataSourceSchema)
{
    bool isValid = true;

    if (importData.Columns.Count != importDataSourceSchema.Columns.Count)
    {
        isValid = false;
        ValidationLabel.Text = ValidationLabel.Text + "<br />Wrong number of columns";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < importData.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (importData.Columns[i].ColumnName != importDataSourceSchema.Columns[i].ColumnName)
        {
            ValidationLabel.Text = ValidationLabel.Text + "<br />Error finding column " + importData.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

I then call ValidateHeaders prior to performing a the bulk import

```
if (ValidateHeaders(importData, importDataSourceSchema))
{
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy([Add your ConnectionString here]))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.EmployeeImport";
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("FirstName", "FirstName"));
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("LastName", "LastName"));
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Hire Date", "HireDate"));
        try
        {
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(importData);
            ValidationLabel.Text = "Success";
            GridView1.DataSource = importData;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ValidationLabel.Text = e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

**Below is full proof of concept code written for ASP.NET WebForms**

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EmployeeImport.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.EmployeeImport" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

         <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload" 
            onclick="UploadButton_Click" />

        <br />
        Data Imported: <asp:Label ID="ValidationLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class EmployeeImport : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string GetDateTimeStampedFolderName()
        {
            return string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}", DateTime.Now);
        }

        public void CreateSchemIni(string targetFolder, string fileName)
        {
            using (FileStream filestr = new FileStream(targetFolder + "/schema.ini", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filestr))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("[" + FileUpload1.FileName + "]");
                    writer.WriteLine("ColNameHeader=True");
                    writer.WriteLine("Format=CSVDelimited");
                    writer.WriteLine("Col1=FirstName Text");
                    writer.WriteLine("Col2=LastName Text");
                    writer.WriteLine("Col3=\"Hire Date\" Text");
                    writer.Close();
                    writer.Dispose();
                }
                filestr.Close();
                filestr.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private bool ValidateHeaders(DataTable importData, DataTable importDataSourceSchema)
        {

            bool isValid = true;

            if (importData.Columns.Count != importDataSourceSchema.Columns.Count)
            {
                isValid = false;
                ValidationLabel.Text = ValidationLabel.Text + "<br />Wrong number of columns";
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < importData.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (importData.Columns[i].ColumnName != importDataSourceSchema.Columns[i].ColumnName)
                {
                    ValidationLabel.Text = ValidationLabel.Text + "<br />Error finding column " + importData.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                    isValid = false;
                }
            }

            return isValid;
        }

        private void UploadAndImport()
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string targetFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Employees/" + GetDateTimeStampedFolderName());

                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetFolder) == false)
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetFolder);
                }

                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(targetFolder, FileUpload1.FileName));



                string strSql = "SELECT * FROM [" + FileUpload1.FileName + "]";
                string strCSVConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + targetFolder + ";" + "Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;'";
                using (OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, strCSVConnString))
                {
                    DataTable importData = new DataTable();
                    DataTable importDataSourceSchema = new DataTable();

                    // Fill the schema prior to creating the schema.ini, as this is the only way to get the headers from the CSV
                    oleda.FillSchema(importDataSourceSchema, System.Data.SchemaType.Source);
                    CreateSchemIni(targetFolder, FileUpload1.FileName);
                    oleda.Fill(importData);

                    if (ValidateHeaders(importData, importDataSourceSchema))
                    {
                        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy([Add your ConnectionString here], SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock))
                        {
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.EmployeeImport";
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("FirstName", "FirstName"));
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("LastName", "LastName"));
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Hire Date", "HireDate"));
                            try
                            {
                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(importData);
                                ValidationLabel.Text = "Success";
                                GridView1.DataSource = importData;
                                GridView1.DataBind();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                ValidationLabel.Text = e.Message;
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                ValidationLabel.Text = "";
                UploadAndImport();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    oleda.Fill(importData);
}
catch(Exception) // put break point here
{
    throw;
}
```

see if you get any exceptions now

Comment: The problem is it does not create an exception. It silently converts bad data to null values. However, I did come up with a solution with I will post shortly.